# remoteMessage.getMessageType returns null in onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

    String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){

        Log.i(TAG," input string :"+ String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData()));
        /**
         * Parse remote input and pass id, action, frequency and payload to eventHandler.
         * **/

        String messageType = remoteMessage.getMessageType();// messageType is null always
        if(messageType.equalsIgnoreCase("Data")){
            Log.i(TAG, " Data notification received");
        }
        else if(messageType.equalsIgnoreCase("Notification")){
            Log.i(TAG, " Push notification received");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `getMessageType()` is supposed to return. But it seem very unlikely that it returns either `Data` or `Notification`, since [a single message can contain both notification and data information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads).

Comment: Thanks Frank. I just figured a way around it and posted my answer without using getMessageType() per se.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. 
I actually figured out a way to check the message type per se. The following works for me without using getMessageType.

Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

```
    if (data.isEmpty()) { // message type is notification.
        parseDataMessage(remoteMessage);
    } else { // message type is data.
        parseNotificationMessage(remoteMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it looks like it is a parameter you can set when sending messages and using the SDK [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Builder.html#setMessageType(java.lang.String)).

> `public RemoteMessage.Builder setMessageType (String messageType)`

However, when sending messages using the Firebase REST API, I haven't seen the ability to specify a Message Type.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this...

```
  if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().get("your_data_key") != null) {
 String strNotificaiton = getIntent().getExtras().get("your_data_key").toString(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code `onMessageReceived` it worked for me:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    //if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    //if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```